# Cannot install @mui/styles in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I cannot install `@material-ui/core` or `@mui/styles` My React and MUI versions are

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.10",
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
```

When I try to use `makeStyles` it says I need to install `@mui/styles` but when I try to install it it gives the following error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Where am I missing out? I cannot find out the problem.

Comment: Be sure to delete your node_modules folder and perform another `npm install` if you have not done so already.  MUIv4 may still be within the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in https://mui.com/styles/basics/, `@mui/styles` is the Material UI v4 legacy styling solution. There's no guarantee of compatibility with React 18.
If you'd like to continue using `@mui/styles`, the recommendation from the MUI team is to stay on React 17.

Full conversation can be found here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32142

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** create **.npmrc** file in your route directory
and add the following

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
engine-strict=false
```

**Step 2:** in **package.json** file add the following

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
}
```

works for me

Answer (score -1):

The `@material-ui/core` library is from major version 4 (as you can see via the error snippet, `from @material-ui/core@4.12.4`), compared to those that begin with `@mui/...` which belong to major version 5. Material UI v4 only supports up to React 17 (as you can see via the error snippet, `peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"`).

Since you are using React 18, you have to install v5 and not v4. `@mui/styles` is v5, so there is another library in your dependencies that is asking for `@material-ui/core v4` or you accidentally added the wrong library at some point. Check that every Material dependency in your project begins with "@mui" and not "@material-ui"

Comment: This is incorrect, `@mui/styles` is not officially compatible with React 18. See: https://mui.com/styles/basics